# Can't get Child Component ref object from their parent React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component, react-ref

I want to reference a `<div>` and a `<span>` component from the child to the parent.
So i code something like:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    childRef = React.createRef()

    componentDidMount(){
      const childRef1 = this.childRef.current.innerRef1
      const childRef2 = this.childRef.current.innerRef2
     
      //... compute with the references childRef1 and childRef2
  }
 
  render(){
    return(
      <ChildComponent ref={this.childRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

Inside the child i got something like:

```
 class ChildComponent extends Component {
    innerRef1 = React.createRef()
    innerRef2 = React.createRef()
    
 
  render(){
    return(
      <div ref={this.innerRef1}>
         <span ref={this.innerRef2}></span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to get the properties of those tags. Things like getBoundingClientRect(), scrollTop,etc; but from the Parent component because i can't compute it from the ChildComponent componentDidMount because those component aren't rendered yet.

That's is my current result from browser console:
[image]

As you can see, the `current object` shows me a `null` value, but inside you can see all the properties that i want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to get the properties of those tags like getBoundingClientRect(). I have provided the example where I called getBoundingClientRect() using ref and also I set a string into innerText of span. Please check it.

**Parent Component Example**

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponentExample from "./ChildComponentExample";

export default class ParentComponentExample extends React.Component {
    childRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        const childRef1 = this.childRef.current.innerRef1;
        const childRef2 = this.childRef.current.innerRef2;

        console.log(childRef2, 'childRef2');
        childRef2.current.innerText = 'This is SPAN';
        const rect = childRef1.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(rect, 'rect');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildComponentExample ref={this.childRef}/>
        )
    }
}
```

**Child Component Example**

```
import React from "react";

export default class ChildComponentExample extends React.Component {
    innerRef1 = React.createRef();
    innerRef2 = React.createRef();

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.innerRef1}>
                <span ref={this.innerRef2}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```